# Running several WordPress sites on same core / plugins?

Tags: multisite, hosting

Is it possible to run more than one site on the same WordPress core and a set of plugins?

I want to be able to have custom plugins and themes for each site, but have a base set that is the same, to make it easier to maintain.

Comment: Do you want to have the files only once or is it okay to have sort of packages and a repository that your several sites are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [it is possible](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).

You can setup subdomains sites like this: `subdomain1.domain.com`, `subdomains2.domain.com`.

Then, after you setup the network, use a domain mapping plugin to setup a domain name for each of them. `subdomain1.domain.com` becomes `domain1.com`, `subdomain2.domain.com` becomes `domain2.com`, etc.

There are several domain mapping plugins out there:

- http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/domain-mapping (the one I would recommend, but it is on a paid membership site)
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/ (free one, but I never used it)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [WordPress MU Domain Mapping (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) is handy for that? Just like running a Multisite installation and offer Plugins in the Network.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a linux platform and you have SSH access to modify or do work inside the server, maybe creating symlink to the core or plugin would work. Just a thought though :)